# boundary values of a holomorphic function vs extension of the function to the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, smooth-functions

Let $\Omega$ be a domain (i.e. open and connected subset) in the complex plane $\mathbb C$. Let $b\Omega$ be its boundary and $\overline{\Omega}=\Omega\cup b\Omega$. Let $C^\infty(b\Omega)$, $C^\infty(\Omega)$ and $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$ be the set of smooth (i.e.continuous partial derivatives of all orders) functions on $b\Omega$, $\Omega$ and $\overline{\Omega}$ respectively. Finally, let $H(\Omega)$ be the set of holomorphic functions on $\Omega$.

I read the following theorem and it has raised me some questions about boundary values of holomorphic functions and extensions of such functions to the boundary. Let me state the theorem and I' ll make the questions after.

> Suppose that h is a holomorphic function $\Omega$ that extends to be a continuous function on $\overline{\Omega}$. If the boundary values of h are in $C^\infty(b\Omega)$, then $h\in C^\infty(\overline\Omega)$.

In other words, there exists a function $\tilde{h}$ such that $\tilde{h}\in C(\overline{\Omega})$ and such that $\tilde{h}=h$ on $\Omega$. The conclusion of the theorem can be stated like this: "then $\tilde{h}\in C^\infty(\overline\Omega)$". Since $\tilde{h}=h$ on $\Omega$ (from the hypothesis), it is obvious that $h\in C^\infty(\Omega)$, since then $\tilde{h}\in H(\Omega)\subset C^\infty(\Omega)$. Also,
from the hypothesis, we have that the boundary values of h, from now noted $b.v.h$, are in $C^\infty(b\Omega)$.

Now the question(s):

1. If we haven't prove the theorem. Can we say that $\tilde{h}=b.v.h$ on $b\Omega$?
2. Does the conclusion of the theorem imply that $\tilde{h}=b.v.h$ on $b\Omega$?
3. Can the function $b.v.h$ be different from the continuous extension of h on $b\Omega$?

If I understand this correctly, the $b.v.h$, even if it is smooth, can be different from the extension of the $h\in H(\Omega)$ to the boundary of $\Omega$, even if the extension is continuous?

Comment: Can you give a reference for the theorem?

Comment: How do you define $b.v.$ $h$ precisely?

Comment: @Caffeine The Cauchy transform, potential theorem and combormal mapping by Steven R. Bell

Comment: @SeanNemetz For a ζ in bΩ $b.v.h=lim_{z\to\zeta} h(z)$. I think that's the meaning.

Comment: Note that, in the book you referred to, $\Omega$ is also finitely connected

Comment: Well, by your definition $\tilde{h}=h$ on your open domain. So using the fact that $\tilde{h}$ is continuous on the closure, can you show 1 and/or 2?

Comment: this follows from a general theorem which says that if $f$ analytic in the unit disc, $f' \in H^1$ if and only if $f$ extends to an absolutely continuous function on the closed disc, and then the radial limit of $f'$ (which exists ae by general Hardy space theory) is the same up to parametrization as the derivative of $f$ on the circle (which exists ae also since $f$ is absolutely continuous on the circle); in particular if $f$ extends continuously to the disc and the circle limit is $C^{\infty}$, we can apply inductively the above and get that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ in the closed unit disc

Comment: @SeanNemetz Yes. Take a ζ on bΩ and a z in Ω. z(t)=tζ+(1-t)z is the line connecting those 2 points. $\tilde{h}(z(t))\to\tilde{h}(z(1))$ when $t\to 1$ and from the continuity we have 1. Now for 2. The conclusion imply the equality for every partial derivative. Not only that equality. So the theorem tells us what the partial derivatives of $h$ do?